# Unity-trying to adjust brightness

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class DayNight : MonoBehaviour{}

// Use this for initialization
void start (){
private float, smooth = 0.0000000000005;
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


IEnumerator IntensityChanging ()
{
    float intensityA = 0.05f;
    float intensityB = 5f;;
    while( 1 == 1){
        newIntensity = intensityA;
        newIntensity = intensityB;

        light.intensity = Math.Lerp(light.intensity, newIntensity, smooth *       Time.deltaTime);
        }
}

}
```

Errors
Assets/Scripts/DayNight.cs(7,15): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `private'
Assets/Scripts/DayNight.cs(6,14): error CS0116: A namespace can only contain types and namespace declarations
Assets/Scripts/DayNight.cs(13,39): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol`(', expecting `)',`,', `;',`[', or `='
Assets/Scripts/DayNight.cs(10,14): error CS0116: A namespace can only contain types and namespace declarations
Assets/Scripts/DayNight.cs(25,1): error CS8025: Parsing error

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

All that code is just unusable, it seems a lot of copypaste's without no sense.

The most approximated I can think is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class DayNight : MonoBehaviour{

    private float smooth = 0.0000000000005;
    // Use this for initialization
    void start (){

    }

    float accumulate = 0;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

        float intensityA = 0.05f;
        float intensityB = 5f;

        accumulate += Time.deltaTime;

        light.intensity = Math.Lerp(intensityA, intensityB, smooth * accumulate);


    }

}
```

The only problem with that code is that light comes from nowhere, you need the reference to the light.